# Traverse a JSON file and flatten it along the way with slashes in C#

Tags: c#, json, nested, json.net

I'm new to JSON and I'm trying to flatten a large JSON file with slashes separating each level. At the basis, I'm trying to have the value either be a single int or string, or list of strings (separated by a comma).
For example, if the JSON looked like this:

```
{
  "This": {
    "Is": {
      "A": [
        "json",
        "file"
      ],
      "Another": {
        "JSON": "File"
      }
    },
    "File": {
      "Is": 4,
      "Line": [
        {
          "Nested": "JSON"
        },
        {
          "Nested2:": "JSON2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It would flatten out to:

`This / Is / A : json, file`

`This / Is / Another / JSON : file`

`This / File / Is : 4`

`This / File / Line / Nested : JSON`

`This / File / Line / Nested 2 : JSON2`

I saw a Javascript solution on StackOverflow that said to do something like this:

```
function traverse(jsonObj) {
    if( jsonObj !== null && typeof jsonObj == "object" ) {
        Object.entries(jsonObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            // key is either an array index or object key
            traverse(value);
        });
    }
    else {
        // jsonObj is a number or string
    }
}
```

But I'm confused, how would I be able to add slashes between the keys as I traverse?
Also note that I am looking for a C# solution, not Javascript.

---

Ok so I tried to take a crack at this. I am using the Newtonsoft.Linq library. My JSON file has values that are ints, strings, lists, objects, and lists of objects.  I wanted to save all the flattened responses to a dictionary (instead of writing it to console). But I run into the issue where the key already exists in the dictionary. This is in the case where there is a list of objects and the list of objects key is the same because they follow a pattern block, but the value is different. Example:

```
{
  "Level1": [
    {
      "Level2": {
        "A": "something1",
        "B": 1
      },
      "Level3": [
        {
          "3A": "content"
        }
      ],
      "Level41": null,
      "Level42": null,
      "Level43": null,
      "Level44": "content",
      "Level45": "content",
      "Level46": "content"
    },
    {
      "Level2": {
        "A": "something1",
        "B": 2
      },
      "Level3": [
        {
          "3A": "morecontent"
        }
      ],
      "Level41": null,
      "Level42": null,
      "Level43": null,
      "Level44": "content",
      "Level45": "morecontent",
      "Level46": "content"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that if the dictionary has already seen the key, it saves all values of that key in a list? Or is that not my issue here? Here is what I did:

```
// The JSON file has been deserialized into a Dictionary with string key and object value
// We will be saving all the key value pairs we have seen into a Dictionary called dictionary
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,object>();
// I was using a datgridview to input the values in a cell but we can ignore that

private void AddValue(string key, object value)
{
    if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(JObject)) // if key == string, value == object
    {
        foreach (var a in (JObject)value)
        {
            string name = a.Key;
            JToken obj = a.Value;
            AddValue(name + a + " / ", obj);
        }
    }
    else if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(JArray)) // if key == string, value == array
    {
        foreach (var a in (JArray)value)
        {
            if (a.GetType() == typeof(JObject)) // if key == string, value == object
            {
                foreach (var item in (JObject)a)
                {
                    string objectName = item.Key;
                    JToken objValue = item.Value;
                    AddValue(objectName + item + " / ", objValue);
                }
            }
            else //key == string, value == string
            {
                string name = (string)a;
                AddValue(name + " / ", a);
            }
        }
    }
    else // key == string, value == string
    {
    var keyCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    var row = new DataGridViewRow();
    var valCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    if (value != null)
    {
        keyCell.Value = key;
        valCell.Value = value;
        row.Cells.Add(keyCell);
        row.Cells.Add(valCell);
        this.treeView.Rows.Add(row);
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey((string)keyCell.Value)) // this is if 
        {
            string optionKey = (string)keyCell.Value;
            object keyValueObject = dictionary[(string)keyCell.Value];
            //values.Add((string)valCell.Value);
            dictionary.Remove((string)keyCell.Value);
        }
        dictionary.Add((string)keyCell.Value, null); // I know this isn't right, because then this just overrides the key each time. Not sure how to fix
        else
        {
            keyCell.Value = key;
            valCell.Value = String.Empty;
            row.Cells.Add(keyCell);
            row.Cells.Add(valCell);
            this.datagridview.Rows.Add(row);
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey((string)keyCell.Value))
            {
                values.Add((string)valCell.Value);
                dictionary.Remove((string)keyCell.Value);
            }
            dictionary.Add((string)keyCell.Value, values);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:c#] but are you really writing in c#?  The sample solution isn't c#, it looks like [tag:javascript].  Please confirm.

Comment: The sample solution is from here on Stackoverflow, it was javascript but I am looking for C#

Comment: What do you mean by *"save the keys with parenthesis"*?  In your example output, where exactly would the parenthesis go?  Also, your input JSON is not valid; it is missing quotes, braces and colons in places.  Please provide a valid JSON sample.

Comment: For the `"A"` array you output a single line `json, file` but for the `"Line"` array you output multiple lines.  How do you decide which to do?

Comment: I gave an example of "save the keys with parenthesis": 
This / Is / Another / JSON
Every time it's nested one level, a parenthesis is tacked on.

Comment: `/` is a slash.  Is that what you mean?  Parentheses are `(` and `)`

Comment: So sorry Brian yes that's what I meant, slash, not parenthesis.  Thanks for catching that, I'll update the post.

Comment: What does it mean to "flatten" a json object? What do you hope to get in return? Can you explain the output you would like to see, in C#/.NET terms?

Comment: I removed the "slash" tag as per the [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slash): *Please do not use this tag.*

Comment: Please paste correct json. Your second sample is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects), you can flatten your JSON to a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` like this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);

Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = 
    jo.Descendants()
      .OfType<JProperty>()
      .Where(jp => jp.Value is JValue || 
                   (jp.Value is JArray && jp.Value.Children().All(jt => jt is JValue)))
      .Select(jp => new 
      {
          Path = Regex.Replace(jp.Path, @"\[\d+\]", "").Replace(".", " / "),
          Value = jp.Value is JValue 
              ? (string)jp.Value 
              : string.Join(", ", jp.Value.Children().Select(jt => (string)jt))
      })
      .GroupBy(a => a.Path)
      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(a => a.Value).ToList());
```

This code is a bit dense, so here's a step-by-step breakdown of how it works:

1. Parse the JSON into a JObject so we can query against it:

   ```
    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
   ```
2. Create a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` from the `JObject` as follows:

   ```
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict =
   ```
3. Get all descendants of the JObject in depth-first order, which will include JObjects, JArrays, JProperties (key-value pairs within JObjects) and JValues (primitives):

   ```
     jo.Descendants()
   ```
4. Filter the descendants down to just the properties (the key-value pairs):

   ```
       .OfType<JProperty>()
   ```
5. We are only interested in properties having a value that is either a primitive (e.g. string, int) or an array containing only primitives.  So next we filter the properties to only those meeting that criteria:

   ```
       .Where(jp => jp.Value is JValue || 
                    (jp.Value is JArray && 
                     jp.Value.Children().All(jt => jt is JValue)))
   ```
6. Now that we have the properties we want, we need to extract the path and value (s) from each one per the requirements.  We will select these into a temporary anonymous object to make it easier to do further processing on them later.

   ```
       .Select(jp => new 
       {
   ```

   To do the paths with slashes we can make use of the handy `Path` property on the `JProperty`.  This will return a dot-separated path, such as `This.File.Line[0].Nested`, which is pretty close to what you are looking for.  However, we need to get rid of the array subscripts (e.g. `[0]`) and replace the dots with slashes:

   ```
           Path = Regex.Replace(jp.Path, @"\[\d+\]", "").Replace(".", " / "),
   ```

   For the value part, what we do depends on whether the value is a primitive or an array of primitives.  If it's just a simple primitive, we just get its value as a string; if it's an array, we join all of its children (as strings) together into a comma-delimited list:

   ```
           Value = jp.Value is JValue 
               ? (string)jp.Value 
               : string.Join(", ", jp.Value.Children().Select(jt => (string)jt))
        }
   ```
7. Since we eliminated the array subscripts there is the possibility of duplicate keys now.  We want to be able to put everything into a dictionary, so we need to group together the values having the same paths:

   ```
        .GroupBy(a => a.Path)
   ```
8. Once we have the groups we can convert everything to a dictionary by putting the values into a list for each key (path):

   ```
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(a => a.Value).ToList())
   ```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2VeAhY

Comment: brian can you check out what i did above:

Comment: Is this what you are ultimately looking for?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/2VeAhY

Comment: Just saw this! Oh wow this is quite impressive Brian, thank you! The regex is quite complex, I'm going to see if I can convert what you've done :)

Answer (score 0):

`JToken` has a useful `Path` property.  With its help this short code:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
var json = JObject.Parse(text);

var result = json.Descendants()
    .Where(t => !t.HasValues)
    .Select(t => t.Path.Replace(".", " / ") + " : " + t.ToString());

foreach (var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

gives the following result:

```
This / Is / A[0] : json
This / Is / A[1] : file
This / Is / Another / JSON : File
This / File / Is : 4
This / File / Line[0] / Nested : JSON
This / File / Line[1] / Nested2: : JSON2
```

To be continued...